# Find Version of GWT Running On Site

Tags: gwt, version

Is it possible to send a javascript command to a site and determine the GWT version running in the browser? The reason I ask is because our QA folks are certifying our software and need a way to look at the version running without taking our word for it by looking at the IDE.

I know that I can do `java -jar gwt-dev.jar`, but normally we do not deploy that with the software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The built-in GWT linkers generate a `$gwt_version` variable in the `*.cache.*` files.

Assuming you don't have other frames in your app, your GWT app will be in the first frame so you can then get the GWT version used to compile it with `frames[0].$gwt_version`.

Comment: So, `javascript:frames['myapp'].$gwt_version` in the same browser URL bar as my GWT application in Firefox?

Comment: Which linker are you using? (any `<add-linker>` in your `*.gwt.xml`?)

Comment: I searched my gwt.xml and there are no linker entries. However, I looked at one of the *.cache.* files and I can see $gwt_version declared. I am using Netbeans 7.2.1

Comment: Ah, sorry, `frames['myapp']` doesn't work. `frames[0]` worked for me, see edited answer.